# How to show digital signature VALUE in signature appearance of PDF file with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

Is it possible to append Digital signature VALUE in signature appearance while signing document, because I am using this part of code

```
PdfFilename = txtFile.Text + "\\" + (string)chkLista.Items[i];
DestPdfFilename = txtFile.Text + "\\" + (string)chkLista.Items[i] + "-signed.pdf";

Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };
IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-256");
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(PdfFilename);
FileStream signedPdf = new FileStream(DestPdfFilename, FileMode.Create);  //the output pdf file
PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, '\0');
PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;

signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(436, 700, 564, 750), 1, "sig");

MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

but in PDF it shows only the rectangle filled only with data like: Digitally signed by:... and Date:...

Except this I want to be showed digital signature Value in Base64 too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I correctly understand the OP, the task is to display a base64 representation of the actual signature value bytes as the signature field appearance.*

**This is not possible.**

The reason is that the *appearance* of the signature field is part of the signed byte range:

[image: The structure of an example signed PDF]

(The appearance is defined somewhere in the first or third section in the example.)

Therefore, *the appearance must be known **before** the signature value is created.* Thus, the value cannot completely be represented in the field appearance.

For more backgrounds read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096).

That been said, you might try to cheat a bit by adding JavaScript to the PDF which at *display time* changes the appearance of the signature field. This approach has two drawbacks, though:

- Not all PDF viewers support JavaScript.
- Adobe Reader and Acrobat, the main PDF viewers also supporting JavaScript, would recognize this change of the appearance and indicate that the signature is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I know This is a very old question and it was answered by @mki, and the answer is accepted.

I am going to post the answer for anyone who requires it nowadays.

Recently I customized the signature displaying appearance, and works for me.

```
sap.Layer2Text = "Digitally signed by " + PdfPKCS7.GetSubjectFields(chain(0)).GetField("CN") + Constants.vbCrLf + "Designation: President & Head – Cards & Payments" + Constants.vbCrLf + "Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + Constants.vbCrLf + "Entity: Pulkitsoft";
```

Note: **sap** is a PdfSignatureAppearance